# Como alterar a cor de um botão?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Estou fazendo alguns experimentos para conhecer melhor a IDE Netbeans e fiquei com essa dúvida sobre coloração de uma botão.

Clicando com o botão direito sobre um jButton qualquer e selecionando Propriedades, configuro o item *background* na cor verde, por exemplo, mas somente a borda do botão fica com a cor selecionada.

[image: jButton antes da alteração]
`JButton` antes da alteração em Propriedades

[image: jButton depois da alteração]
`JButton` depois da alteração em Propriedades

Já alterei o LAF para Windows e retornei para Nimbus (padrão) e não ocorre nada de diferente.

É possível alterar a cor de preenchimento de um botão?

Comment: Eu já respondi sua pergunta, mas se você não fornecer um **[mcve]** não tem como eu verificar o problema. A solução abaixo é funcional.

Comment: Só agora que vi seu comentário. Estou usando o editor gráfico do Netbeans e coloquei as capturas da pequena tela para demonstrar o que está acontecendo, pois o Netbeans gera muito código que ficaria confuso postar aqui. Esse é meu exemplo mínimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para alterar a cor, basta utilizar [`setBackground()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground-java.awt.Color-) passando a cor desejada através da classe [`Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html), usando suas constantes ou criando cores personalizadas:

```
botao.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Porém, a maioria dos [LookAndFeels(LAF)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) já tem configurações padrão de cores e mesmo alterando o método acima, não permite alterar corretamente em alguns casos. Para resolver isso, você precisa "remover" essa estilização do componente, através dos métodos abaixo:

```
    botao.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    botao.setOpaque(true);
    botao.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Obs.: Ao fazer isso, você está abrindo mão de todas as estilizações feitas pelo LAF, e não somente das cores de background e foreground.

Comment: Encontrei essa sequência de configurações em Propriedades do botão. Como estou usando o editor gráfico do Netbeans, somente selecionei/deselecionei os itens que passou e funcionou. Só não conhecia esse efeito colateral que mencionou

Comment: @AnonReports não dá pra programar interface sem mexer no código. É recomendável que você aprenda a manusear o código, senão você vai perder tempo criando interface e depois resolvendo problemas com o código gerado pela ide, que é imenso e confuso.

Comment: É só alterar as propriedades do item em suas propriedades! O Netbeans não permite que seu código gerado seja alterado, poucos trechos são livres para edição, mas a grande parte (quando se trabalha com GUI) é protegida. Não se incomode, deletei minha conta! o/